# Compilation failure when deducing the return type of an auto function in an unevaluated context

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, template-meta-programming

I have some machinery `get_return_type` that can be used in an unevaluated context to deduce the return type of a function without needing to supply the argument types:

```
template <typename Result, typename... Args>
Result get_return_type(Result (*)(Args...));

int example(double, char, bool);

// will be int
using result_type = decltype(get_return_type(example));
```

However if the function is a template, and its return type is `auto`, all version of GCC I've tried fail to compile. Clang works perfectly.

```
namespace TemplatedFunctionReturningAutoTest
{
    template <typename T>
    auto foo(T v) { return v; }

    // GCC complains that Result type cannot be deduced in
    // template substitution of get_return_type
    static_assert(std::is_same<int, decltype(get_return_type(foo<int>))>::value, "");
}
```

Here it is on godbolt (gcc 6.2): https://godbolt.org/g/iIh6TU

If you switch to clang 3.x it works fine! It feels like GCC is reluctant to instantiate the body of the function to figure out its return type.

Is this a GCC bug, or is there something in the standard that prevents this from working?

Comment: This appears to be equivalent to `std::result_of`. Do you still get the compilation error with gcc, if you use `std::result_of`?

Comment: Not quite. `result_of` requires you to supply all the argument types to figure out the return type. (for the `example` function above, I would need to provide `double`, `char` and `bool`)

Comment: I just did a test using `result_of`, and it works fine, but I don't want to supply the argument types (I'm lazy :P)

Comment: I suspect that gcc simply deduces that the return type, in this case, is `auto`. I think that gcc is right, but I won't go on the record with it.

Comment: `auto` is not a type though... that doesn't make sense. Also, the error clearly states that `Result` type could not be deduced.

Comment: Well, not exactly. `auto` is a type. Which gets replaced by the real type when the template is expanded. You could declare a function `auto foo(int);`, then have specialization either work or not work, depending on whether the function's body is defined. This seems wrong. Whether or not a template parameter is matched by a specialization should not depend on the definition of the template parameter. A declaration should be sufficient.

Comment: Sounds like a GCC bug to me.

Comment: Curiously, if I add this line `    int (*f)(int) = &foo;` just before your static assert, then it will compile on gcc, in your godbolt screen. Even if `f` is an unused variable thereafter. So, that is some wierd action-at-a-distance, suggesting a gcc bug